# Automatic-scaling instances doesn't work when using modules on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm creating a GAE app in Python 2.7, with modules and their specific versions. I downloaded the original example from the [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-helloworld-python), as found in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/).

I've deployed everything without problems - however I can't get the `mobile_frontend` module to run, when I try I get an error page. This module is the one with the `automatic_scaling` configured in it's `yaml` file.

The other module - `static_backend` runs without any problems - its the one with `manual_scaling` in it's `yaml` file.

However, when I change over to `manual_scaling` in the `mobile_frontend` module, it starts working. Therefore, I suspect there is a problem in my implementation - although I didn't modify the code provided by Google.

For now, I ignored the issue with the scaling and added some versions of my modules, which work - my repo is [here](https://github.com/MartinHerman/droppie-gae-modules-tester).

Could someone clarify who I'm experiencing this problem with the `automatic_scaling` configuration? I've even tried to create a new app, no success tho.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean can't get the module to run? what error do you encountered?

Comment: the description in your repo won't work, you don't have mobile_frontend.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curiously - for some reason the same configuration started working some 12 hours later. I don't know if Google only enables some features some time after the app has been created or launched, but it simply appears that way. Or maybe they fixed it silently...

However, I'm still getting this message in my Terminal, when updating the whole app (although I see no problems):

> Performance settings included in this update are being ignored because
>   your application is not using the Modules feature. See the Modules
>   documentation for more information. Python:
>   (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) Java:
>   (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) Go:
>   (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/modules/) PHP:
>   (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/).